# Error while creating continuous export of azure log to storage using powershell command

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to create ContinuousExport for Azure Application Insights Logs to Storage Container using Powershell cmd, but I am getting below error
**New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport: Exception calling "Join" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'values')"**

Comment: Can you provide your code that you're attempting to run?

Comment: @BrettMiller, Yes

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "name" -StorageAccountKey "key1"
$sastoken= New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Name "name" -Context $context -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddYears(50) -Permission w
$sasuri = "http" + $sastoken
New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport -ResourceGroupName "name" -Name "name" -DocumentType "Custom Event" -StorageAccountId "storageaccid" -StorageLocation locationname -StorageSASUri $sasuri